# python append an array with a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

How to append an array with a dictionary inside a dictionary?

```
d1 = {
'a':'a',
'b':'b'
}

d2 = {
'c':'c',
'd':'d'
}

maindict = {
'1':'1',
'array':[] #append d1, d2 here
}
```

to be like

```
maindict = {
'1':'1',
'array':[d1, d2, ...] #append d1, d2 here
}

maindict = {
'1':'1',
'array':[{},{}, ...] #append d1, d2 here
}
```

Comment: what do you want the end result to look like? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression ?

Comment: @Boris it needs to be an `array` of `dicts` inside the main `dict`.

Comment: @KapishM Please provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My answer is tested and works with the code you provided...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You append to it like you would any other array, with `.append`:

```
maindict['array'].append(d1)

maindict['array'].append(d2)
```

Comment: I should mention, I tried append. it say 'dict' has no method append

Comment: @KapishM I don't see how that's possible, unless something is different in your code.